# ASP.NET - controls generated by xslt transformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

i'm generating controls dynamically on my asp.net page by xslt transformation from an xml file. i will need to reference these controls from code behind later. i would like to add these references to the list/hashtable/whatever during creation (in xslt file i suppose) so that i could reach them later and i have no idea how to do this.
i will be absolutely grateful for any suggestions,
agnieszka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have transformed your XML using XSLT, you could pass the output to the ASP.Net [ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28.aspx) method and it will return your controls ready to use.  For example this code will place two buttons on the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Fetch your XML here and transform it.  This string represents
    // the transformed output
    string content = @"
        <asp:Button runat=""server"" Text=""Hello"" />
        <asp:Button runat=""server"" Text=""World"" />";

    var controls = ParseControl(content);

    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        // Wire up events, change settings etc here
    }

    // placeHolder is simply an ASP.Net PlaceHolder control on the page
    // where I would like the controls to end up
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(controls);
}
```

Comment: Ha! Then I learned something new and useful from SO today as well! :-)

Comment: I tried this and get: foreach statement cannot operate variable of type System.Web.UI.Control because System.Web.UI.Control does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a better idea of what you are trying to do?

XML > XSLT > produces aspx page

Sounds close to reinventing the windows presentation framework or XUL

Or is it
ASPX reads xml > uses XSLT to add DOM elements to page...
Sounds like AJAX

You want to write out a unique ID using the attribute transform
http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_attribute.asp

Answer (score 0):

Could be tricky with a pure XSL solution.

You might be able to call a template which iterates the xml nodes you are using generate the controls, and writes out a c#/VB script block which adds them to a container of your choice.

Another option could be to add msxsl:script to your template, and use c# or another language to generate the output you want. This can sometimes be easier than a pure xsl solution, but does come with a performance cost.

It might be worth having a look at the source code of umbraco, which utilises xsl pretty heavily, and possibly already does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.

This is what i do (it's not my code, but i'm doing it the same way):

private void CreateControls()
{
    XPathDocument surveyDoc = new XPathDocument(Server.MapPath("ExSurvey.xml"));

```
// Load the xslt to do the transformations
XslTransform transform = new XslTransform();
transform.Load(Server.MapPath("MakeControls.xslt"));

// Get the transformed result
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
transform.Transform(surveyDoc, null, sw);
string result = sw.ToString();

// parse the control(s) and add it to the page
Control ctrl = Page.ParseControl(result);
form1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

}

First solution (from Generic Error) is not good enough, because i need to identify the controls, for example during xslt transformation i will create 3 groups of controls, all having different ids. I would like to put references to each control from a group in different hashtable so that i would know later which controls are in each group.

The best solution would be to do it somehow when creating a control (so in xslt code..) but i don't know if it's possible.